# Rewrite rule for nginx-ingress in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am struggling with making a rewrite/redirect rule on nginx-ingress on Kubernetes.

According to the doc https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/ it says it is possible with the annotation "`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`", but unable to implement on my ingress. Maybe I am doing it wrong.

An example, portion of nginx-ingress yaml file.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    example.com/deployment-name: frontend-page
    example.com/ingress-hostnames: www.example.com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: frontend-page
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /front(/|$)(.*)
```

Tried another way around as well but no luck:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    example.com/deployment-name: frontend-page
    example.com/ingress-hostnames: www.example.com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /shop
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: frontend-page
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
```

I want to redirect any traffic to the page `www.example.com/front/checkdomain` to `www.example.com/checkdomain`. I want to remove that "front" path comes in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was

Changing from:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

To:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2/
```

So the yaml looks like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    example.com/deployment-name: frontend-page
    example.com/ingress-hostnames: www.example.com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2/
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: frontend-page
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /front(/|$)(.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this with an updated API version, hope your ingress supports `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

Example : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#examples

Comment: When I try to change the apiVersion line, save and exit and apply, it shows an error. Does that mean the apiVersion is not supported by the running nginx-ingress?

Comment: you might be doing other mistake possibly you can try applying the yaml and also don't forget to delete your old testing ingress of this domain. keep this one if API version not supported k8s will give error when applying the yaml.  which k8s version are you using ?

Comment: i think it will work try with applying the yaml

Comment: ok Harsh, what I have been trying so far with edit command `kubectl edit ingress frontend-page -n app -o yaml`. Did you mean to delete this file and apply a fresh one with changes?

Comment: yes try with the fresh instead of editing it, so that can verify API version issue also If not supported.

Comment: I deleted the existing ingress and applied the new yml file with `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`. It applied without any error, but when checking the output of ingress using `-o yaml` output, I can see it automatically replaced back to `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1`. I don't know why. Is that due to any incompatibility in api version?

Comment: Ingress works but no redirection takes place, now the page shows a 404 error.